# Changing SAS code to create more succinct code

Tags: sas

I have created a piece of code below, and it works well but I would like to change the many do
loops  and if statements I have in one part of the code with 1 do loop and an if statement. You
can see the code I wanna change between these two code comments

1. - Code for creating a flag for Looping consecutive months;
     2, * End of Code for creating a flag for Looping consecutive months;

Basically I would just like to make the code more succinct

```
data want;
set have;
array pays(*) pay_201501--pay_202212;
array months(*) month1-month96;
array flag(*) flag1-flag96;

* populate with first day of each month extracted from var name;
do _i = 1 to 96;
    months(_i) = input(scan(vname(pays(_i)), -1, '_'), yymmn6.);
end;



* ensure the dates are properly bounded;
format strt_dt end_dt date9.;
strt_dt = intnx('month', max(startdate, '1jan2015'd), 0);
end_dt = intnx('month', min(enddate, '31dec2022'd), 0);



* find the index of months array that matches the dates;
strt_indx = whichn(strt_dt, of months(*));
end_indx = whichn(end_dt, of months(*));



* validate the indices accurately reflect the true var;
strt_vname = vname(pays(strt_indx));
end_vname = vname(pays(end_indx));



* Code for creating a flag for Looping consecutive months;

if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+3]=1;
  end;
if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+4]=1;
  end;
if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+5]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+5]=1;
  end;
if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+5]^=0
    and pays[_i+6]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+6]=1;
  end;
  if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
  if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+5]^=0
    and pays[_i+6]^=0
    and pays[_i+7]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+7]=1;
  end;
  if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
  if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+5]^=0
    and pays[_i+6]^=0
    and pays[_i+7]^=0
    and pays[_i+8]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+8]=1;
  end;
  if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
  if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+5]^=0
    and pays[_i+6]^=0
    and pays[_i+7]^=0
    and pays[_i+8]^=0
    and pays[_i+9]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+9]=1;
  end;
  if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
  if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+5]^=0
    and pays[_i+6]^=0
    and pays[_i+7]^=0
    and pays[_i+8]^=0
    and pays[_i+9]^=0
    and pays[_i+10]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+10]=1;
  end;
   if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag[_i]= 1);
  if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0
  and pays[_i+4]^=0
  and pays[_i+5]^=0
  and pays[_i+6]^=0
    and pays[_i+7]^=0
  and pays[_i+8]^=0
  and pays[_i+9]^=0
  and pays[_i+10]^=0
  and pays[_i+11]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag[_i+11]=1;
  end;



do _i = 1 to 96;
if flag[_i] = '' then flag[_i] = 0;
else flag[_i] = 1;
end;

 * End of Code for creating a flag for Looping consecutive months;

drop _: monthly_pay: month:;
run
;
```

Comment: Probably better on the Code Review Stack. But you need to look at the algorithm and work out what happens when to reduce the code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my section on dynamic code here: https://github.com/savian-net/SasTipsTricks?tab=readme-ov-file#dynamic-code

Basically, use a PUT statement to dynamically gen the code then %INCLUDE it back in:

```
            filename TEMP 'c:\temp\Test.sas';

        data _null_ ;
           file TEMP ;
           set DICT end=eof;
           if _n_ = 1 then
              do ;
                 put 'data Africa ; '
                   / ' attrib '
                   ;
              end;
           if label = "" then
              put @12 name @30 'label="XX_' name +(-1) '"' ;
           else
              put @12 name @30 'label="XX_' label +(-1)'"' ;
           if eof then
              do ;
                 put @12';'
                      / ' set sashelp.SHOES;'
                      / 'run;'
                      ;
              end;
        run;

        %include TEMP ;
```

Comment: I have a question in a % let statement can arrays be incremented with a + sign              
        for example %let n1 = pays[_i+3]^= 0;                                                                            Do I need to wrap the pays[_i+3] in a %sysfunc or %eval or something?

Comment: I can't answer that since I rarely used arrays. I wrap in do loops and generate the code. Search the SAS-L forum for information from the best SAS coders. SAS-L dates all the way back to the late 80s so everything is there.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are a good way to look for patterns.  Convert your array of 0/1 values into a string. Assuming the variables are listed in the array in order you could probably just use CATS() function.

```
string=cats(of pays[*]);
```

Assuming this is related to your earlier question about finding 9 ones between two groups of 3 zeros then the pattern you want would be the string '000111111111000'.

Then you can just check if the pattern exists anywhere

```
found = index(string,'000111111111000');
```

Or at some particular starting location:

```
do index=1 to length(string);
  found[index] = (substrn(string,index,15) = '000111111111000');
end;
```